# Getting ideas for this combinatory proof

Tags: combinatorics

Given $n$, proof that if we coloured $n$ of the vertexes of a right $2017$-gon in red and all of the others in blue, then the number of monochromatic(a monochromatic triangle is such a triangle which has all its vertices unicoloured) isosceles triangles depends on $n$ but not the way the polygon is coloured

Comment: Here's an idea: The problem doesn't depend on the 2017 and was surely asked last year for a 2016-gon. Thus, try to prove it for a square, for a hexagon, etc. until you see a pattern - then prove this general pattern.

Comment: That is a nice idea